# Dice Rolling (Math Game)

Tags: dice

You wager an amount *W* on the roll of two die. Any 1's win 100 dollars, and any 5's win 50 dollars each, otherwise you lose. For what value of *W* would this be a fair game?

I'm not so concerned with the answer, mostly I just want to know how to set this up.

Comment: By 'fair game', do you mean the probability of winning being 0.5?

Comment: Fair game means that the expected loss is zero. Obviously the probability of winning is going to be $\frac13$.

Comment: Fair usually means that the expected return is 0. Snap!

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the expected value of one play. This will be an expression involving the known payoffs, their probabilities, and the cost $w$. Find the value of $w$ for which the expected value is zero.

Comment: What I did to get the expected value was this... 100(2/12)+50(2/12)+0(8/12)=25 however I feel like this is not correct

Comment: That is not correct. Make a table of each of the 36 possible rolls, and the payoff for that roll. Average the 36 payoffs. This is the expected payoff from one roll.